# Google Search Console reports "Not all page resources could be loaded" when using embedded Youtube videos

Tags: google-search-console, javascript, youtube, resources

I have a blog but I got a message from Google Console:

> #### Page partially loaded
>
> Not all page resources could be loaded. This can affect how Google sees and understands your page. Fix availability problems for any resources that can affect how Google understands your page.

I have 33 blog posts and seems like 11 of them have the issue.  Might be related to my 'embedded Youtube videos'.

But I've uploaded all the content the same way in all blogs.

Comment: Those resources might be thumbnails of the videos? I never had *that* specific error, but don't they tell you *which* resources failed to load? Perhaps try with some other broken-link checker?

Comment: The resources are probably not broken links, they're more likely blocked by robots.txt. Google usually uses this message to complain when parts of a page can't be loaded because of disallows rather than parts of the page giving 404 errors.

Comment: The mobile test tool shows which resources failed. It's not good at showing the reason, but it's a start. At least you'll know if it's something on your site that's failing, and not something external (YouTube embed, etc.) https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly

Comment: Hello everyone.  Thanks so much for all the responses.  That will give me an idea to keep working on it.  What is strange is that I have 40 posts.  And I've done the same pattern on all of them.  I embed one video on each post.  So, as  Hagen von Eitzen mentions, could it be something with the actual thumbnails? How would that work?I did my own thumbnails. Of those 40 posts, seems like the problem is with 11 of them....